# Issue with figuring specific image clicked in JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hey guys so I have an overview I am bulding for products,  the issue is I have this following code:

```
<?php  $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                    $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield'/> ";
                ?>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function()
                                {


                                    $('.item-post a').click(function() {
                                        var num = $('#hiddenpostnumfield').val();
                                    var prodname = $('#hiddenpostitle' + num).val();

                                       $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', 
                                        { 
                                            'ProdName': prodname

                                        },
                                        function(response) {
                                        },
                                        'json'
                                    );
                                    });
                                    $('.item-post a').colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"});
                                });

                            </script>
                <?php 
                $i++;
                $j++;
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So every post, or product that is queried in wordpress get's posted to site, then the JSON sends and creates an Session of the product id and than colorbox opens it,  Now it always takes the last post that is queried and I think that's becuase of the `$('.item-post a').click(function() {`  This is a global variation to each post.

So I guess my question is how do I make it so that it chooses the image(.item-post a) that is clicked for the specific product,  Because it's just choosing every single product no matter which product you select.

I hope this makes sense,  If you could help me I would much appreciate!

Merry Christmas!!!

Answer (score 0):

within `$('.item-post a').click(function() {` you have `$(this)` within that event to work with clicked item.

In a selector you can add `this` as a second parameter to make sure its grabbing from clicked item

```
$('#hiddenpostnumfield', this)
```

Comment: With out having more code it will be hard to help. One question. Does each post have those 2 hidden fields?

Comment: So It is just a big loop that get every post and the hidden value changes upon the $i++ and $j++

Comment: Ok then first off the second one with the id 'hiddenpostnumfield' should be a class not an id. There should never be multiple items with the same id. Secondly check my updated comment above

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item-post a').click(function() {
    $(this); //a jQuery object of the <a> element clicked
});
```